# Toggle divs using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a bit new to jquery so this should be a simple fix. I simply want to toggle divs. When adserver_b is toggled, I hide adserver. However I need this function to be reversed as well. So when adserver_b is visible, it can be clicked to reveal adserver again.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("#ad_server").click(function() {
        $("#ad_serverb").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```
<div id="adserver_contain">
<div id="ad_server"><img src="Images/Adserver_roll.png"></div>
</div>

<div id="ad_serverb"><img src="Images/Adserver.png"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set #ad_serverb display to none so it's hidden. (I gave blocks some style for testing).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ad_server").click(toggleAdServers);
    $("#ad_serverb").click(toggleAdServers);
});

function toggleAdServers(){
  $("#ad_server").fadeToggle();
  $("#ad_serverb").fadeToggle();
}
```

```css
#ad_server, #ad_serverb{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00F;
}
#ad_serverb{
  background: #F00;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adserver_contain">
<div id="ad_server"><img src="Images/Adserver_roll.png"></div>
</div>

<div id="ad_serverb"><img src="Images/Adserver.png"></div>
```

**Edit:** Multiple elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggleElements").each(function() {
    var parent = $(this);
    $(this).find(".first").click(function() {
      $(this).fadeToggle();
      $(parent).find(".second").fadeToggle();
    });
    $(this).find(".second").click(function() {
      $(this).fadeToggle();
      $(parent).find(".first").fadeToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.toggleElements {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.first,
.second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00F;
}
.second {
  background: #F00;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggleElements">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="Images/Adserver_roll.png">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="Images/Adserver.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toggleElements">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="Images/Adserver_roll.png">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="Images/Adserver.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toggleElements">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="Images/Adserver_roll.png">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="Images/Adserver.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be a a dumb question.I am going to be doing this multiple times with different divs will I need to change click(toggle**AdServers**); according to which div I am addressing?

Comment: I hope my update is what you mean.